# json ajax php decode

Tags: php, ajax, json

json хранится в localstorage
Отправляю так

```
    function _onSubmitForm(e) {
            var cartData,               
                orderData;
            e.preventDefault();
            cartData = _getCartData();    
            orderData = formData + '&cart=' + JSON.stringify(cartData);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'scripts/order.php ',
                data: orderData,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                error: _orderError,
                success: function(responce) {
                    if (responce.code === 'success') {
                        _orderSuccess(responce);
                    } else {
                        _orderError(responce);
                    }
                },
                complete: _orderComplete
            });
        }
 function _getCartData() {
        var cartData = cart.getData();
        _.each(cart.getData(), function(item) {
            item.name = encodeURIComponent(item.name);
        });
        return cartData;
    }
```

Обработка в php

```
function sendEmailOrder($data) {
    $cart = json_decode($data['cart']);

    ob_start();
    include('tpl/email_order.php');
    $body = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $sendClient = sendEmail(array(
        'subject' => 'Ваш заказ с сайта ' . SITE,
        'fromName' => EMAIL_FROM_NAME,
        'fromEmail' => EMAIL_ADMIN,
        'toEmail' => $data['email'],
        'body' => $body
    ));

    $sendAdmin = sendEmail(array(
        'subject' => 'Новый заказ с сайта ' . SITE,
        'fromName' => EMAIL_FROM_NAME,
        'fromEmail' => EMAIL_ADMIN,
        'toEmail' => EMAIL_ADMIN,
        'body' => $body
    ));     
}
```

`$cart` в php получается пустым. Ошибка в консоли

> **Invalid** argument supplied for foreach()

Если в ajax запросе сделать alert, выглядит это как

> name:%25B2%24D1%2588%

остальные данные json передаются нормально, и другие поля с русским текстом.

Только name кодируется вот так. Может поэтому проблема? В getCartData() какая-то ошибка?

**Дополнение.**
Убрал проверку

```
'cart' => isset($_POST['cart']) ? stripslashes($_POST['cart']) : '[]'
```

Заменил на

```
'cart' => $_POST['cart']
```

Ошибка пропала. Но поле name все равно приходят кразозябрами. Получается, что это еще на стороне ajax криво кодируется?

Comment: зачем вы делаете stringify перед отправкой и вообще конкатенируете поля в строку, если выполняете post запрос?

Comment: Не могу сказать. "Мотороллер не мой". Что-то не так в ajax, верно?

Comment: Там ведь передается еще и данные формы обратной связи в этом же запросе. Видимо, поэтому такой скрипт. Как мне кажется.

Comment: Думаю надо посмотреть на данные в JSON.stringify(cartData), используйте console.log(JSON.stringify(cartData)) и понять что там не так с данными и почему их json_decode не хочет принимать.

Comment: Вот так выглядит консоль лог. `[{"id":3,"name":"%25D0%259F%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D1%258C%25D0%25B5%2520%25D0%25B1%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B5%2520%25D1%2581%2520%25D1%2580%25D1%2583%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BC","price":0,"photo":5,"rabota":"бордовый","lang":4,"surname":"Строгое классическое платье длина до колена. ","count":2,"days":2},`    И далее другие варианты закодированные так же. name почему-то преобразовывается в эти кракозябры. Хотя в localstorage хранится все в нормальном русском тексте.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась.

```
 function _getCartData() {
        var cartData = cart.getData();
        _.each(cart.getData(), function(item) {
            item.name = encodeURIComponent(item.name);
        });
        return cartData;
    }
```

Убрал лишнее и все заработало.

```
function _getCartData() {
    var cartData = cart.getData();

    return cartData;
}
```

Всем спасибо.